# Cannot access Express web server running on Ubuntu server from outside world

Tags: node.js, http, express, ubuntu, webserver

This is probably one of the most common problems on StackOverflow, but I have tried everything that I know to try.

I just purchased my first domain name with intentions to run a web site on Linode. My Linode public IP is `45.79.142.131`. Just to test that everything is working, I have set up a simple Express web server that serves a simple Hello, World. Server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(80, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 80!'))
```

To allow Express to bind port 80 (note: I will NOT do this for real deployment; this is just a dirty test), I am using the following command:

```
$ sudo node server-80.js 
Example app listening on port 80!
```

If I use `curl` locally on the server, I get a response:

```
$ curl 45.79.142.131:80
Hello World!
```

However, if I use a web browser or curl externally, the server does not provide a response.

```
$ curl 45.79.142.131:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 45.79.142.131 port 80: Operation timed out
```

My first guess was that the firewall was blocking my external request. I am using `ufw` to manage my firewall. I used `` to allow requests on port 80. I also allowed `ssh`, `https`, and a dummy port 3000. I also reloaded the firewall using `sudo ufw reload`.

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Running `nmap` locally on the server provides the following output:

```
$ nmap localhost -Pn

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-27 22:12 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

It would appear that port 80 is open. However, if I run `nmap` externally (i.e. my Mac), I do not see port 80 as being open.

```
$ nmap 45.79.142.131 -Pn
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-27 22:14 EDT
Nmap scan report for li1241-131.members.linode.com (45.79.142.131)
Host is up (0.096s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 47.51 seconds
```

I am at a loss. I don't really know what is happening here. What makes things more strange, though, is that if I run my Express web server on port 3000 (and `sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp`), everything works flawlessly. I am able to get a response from the web server. There is something specific about port 80 that is going wrong. It seems a lot like the firewall is blocking my requests, but I have specifically added an exception for port 80.

If there is any logs or additional information that would help in diagnosing the problem, I am happy to share it.

Comment: Are there any network security group setting on Linode? Check your Linnode security configuration if you can. Because some cloud computing vendors like Azure and Aliyun offer some virtual network subnet security policy to protect your VM.

Comment: I don't think so. I am looking at a Troubleshooting guide published by Linode. Under the Cannot Connect to Web Server section, there is no mention of any special configuration that needs to be done on the Linode instance to allow Port 80 traffic. It does recommend checking if Port 80 is allowed through the firewall. Should I do a `grep` against `iptables` for port 80? Maybe `ufw` caused some misconfiguration somewhere?

Comment: So, I thoughtlessly flushed my `iptables` while also having `ufw` to deny all incoming traffic, so I inadvertently killed my `ssh` connection. I reconfigured my Ubuntu installation from scratch. Fortunately, everything is working now! I can access my dummy server over port 80! The best guess I have is that I accidentally misconfigured my `iptables` when I was first learning to use `ufw` and it somehow affected port 80.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and what worked for me (on Ubuntu 21.10) was allowing the port the nodejs app is using, through the ubuntu firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

To allow all ports (may be less secure), disable the firewall with:

```
ufw disable
```

Answer (score 1):

I thoughtlessly flushed my `iptables` after setting `ufw` to default deny incoming traffic. This killed my `ssh` connection. I completely rebuilt my Ubuntu instance from scratch. When it came time to configure my firewall with `ufw`, I only allowed `ssh` and `http/tcp`. Fortunately, everything appears to be working as expected! I am able to access my dummy web server over port 80.

I don't know what went wrong. The only thing that I can think of is that my `iptables` somehow got into a badly misconfigured state. Maybe I issued a bad command when I was first learning how to use `ufw` or something.